# Marketo REST API - Getting Leads with Email information

Tags: java, rest, api, marketo

I am developing a way to find lead information from a lead's email. I noticed that that most of the ways to receive lead information are via a lead's ID, but did not find any documentation on using an Email to search up leads.

> https://github.com/Marketo/REST-Sample-Code/tree/master/java

This seems to be the best source of where I can find information.

I would like to do this via the REST API in java. Particularly so that I can delete all the found leads from the system. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you're going to want to use the GetLeadsByFilterType/leads.json endpoint with a filterType of email and the email(s) you want to lookup with filterValues (comma separated if you're looking to do a batch.)

Answer (score 0):

Get lead by email:

```
curl -X GET "${baseUrl}rest/v1/leads.json?access_token=${AccessToken}&filterType=email&filterValues=name.lastname@company.com" | jq .
```